# RPI4 with Raspbian OS locked in boot loop after changing watchdog timeouts in `system.conf`

Tags: systemd, boot, raspberry-pi, raspbian, watchdog

In view of **enabling the watchdog** on my **Raspberry Pi 4** running Raspbian (raspberry pi OS) I have modified `/etc/systemd/system.conf` by uncommenting the following three lines:

```
RuntimeWatchdogSec=2min
RebootWatchdogSec=10min
DefaultTimeoutStopSec=10s
```

Now my raspberry is locked in an **infinite boot loop** rebooting every ~2 minutes which is weirdly very similar to the `RuntimeWatchdogSec` value.

I have tried to modify the `/etc/systemd/system.conf` on the SD card using another computer but this does not seem to be the way to go as this file is always being overwritten.

What would be the way to restore these settings by either a) only accessing the SD card from another computer or b) somehow entering a rescue mode/terminal during startup before `systemd` enables this nasty watchdog.

Comment: Just mount it on another system. Path of least resistance.

Comment: This will only allow me to modify `/etc/systemd/system.conf` which does not help as this gets overwritten at each startup. Or is there something better to do? (Might be a naive question but I am not extremely experienced with Unix)